# VB.net Byte Array Search

Tags: arrays, search, byte, virus-scanning

I am in the process of developing a simple virus scanner, and I was searching for speed improvements on the following function:

```
Public Function FindAInB(ByRef byteArrayA() As Byte, ByRef byteArrayB() As Byte) As Integer
    Dim startmatch As Integer = -1
    Dim offsetA As Integer = 0
    Dim offsetB As Integer = 0

    For offsetB = 0 To byteArrayB.Length - 1
        If byteArrayA(offsetA) = byteArrayB(offsetB) Then
            If startmatch = -1 AndAlso offsetB < byteArrayB.Length - 8 Then
                startmatch = offsetB
            End If
            offsetA += 1
            If offsetA = byteArrayA.Length Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            offsetA = 0
            startmatch = -1
        End If
    Next
    Return startmatch
End Function
```

I need it to be turbo fast because it's searching for about 7800 byte arrays in a selected file's bytes. Kind of hard to explain but is there an alternative for the code above or a way to speed it up?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: it all depends on what the data looks like. is it sorted or in random order?

Comment: How large is the arrays - the array you are searching through and the array you are searching for, respectively ?

Comment: Well, strings() is an array of 7281 byte arrays (which are virus signatures), the array i'm searching through is a readAllBytes() of a selected file. searching is done in a do while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out string search algorithms like [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

Although you're not actually searching text, you *are* searching for strings of bytes within a larger string of bytes, so these type of algorithms could help out considerably.

Comment: The problem is that i have to search for a sequence of bytes (that exist in an array) in an array of bytes

Comment: @Seif: Yes, I know. These kind of algorithms can still help. Instead of searching for a small sequence of characters inside a big sequence of characters you're searching for a small sequence of bytes inside a big sequence of bytes. It's exactly the same thing in principle.

Comment: Plus i'm trying to avoid loops that waste time

Comment: @Seif: Well, the Wikipedia page describes the algorithm and has an example implementation in C. I suppose you'd need to translate that into VB.

Comment: @luke: yes but how could that be implemented in byte array searching?